# trigger jquery modal popup on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my first time working with jquery modals. I'm trying to display the popup only when the form is submitted. But instead, it's displaying on page load. How do I fix it?[image]

```
 <script>

  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height: "auto",
  width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "No": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  } );


  </script>


<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Not so fast">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 
20px 0;"></span>Did you want to add a third for only $50? Click Yes to add</p>
</div>

<form id="orderform" action="/action_page.php">
  Package 1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="packageonename" value="">
  <br>
  Package 2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="packagetwoname" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the dialog from automatically opening you can set `autoOpen` property to `false` when initializing the dialog.

Then, on form's submit event, you could open the dialog by calling `element.dialog("open")`.

Note that I have added an `event.preventDefault()` in the submit event handler to prevent the form from submitting.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "No": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

  $("#orderform").on("submit", function(e) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Not so fast">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 
20px 0;"></span>Did you want to add a third for only $50? Click Yes to add</p>
</div>

<form id="orderform" action="/action_page.php">
  Package 1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="packageonename" value="">
  <br> Package 2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="packagetwoname" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much. How would I change it to make it so that clicking "No" will submit the form like normal and continue on?

Comment: @JEP For that, I would change the submit button to a simple button - `type="button"` and listen to click event on the button instead of submit on the form Then you can trigger the form submission from JavaScript using `$("#orderform").submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$('#orderform').submit(function() {

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    return true; // return false to cancel form action
});
```